# User Current Location Prompt

Tags: iphone, location, cllocationmanager

i am deleting and re-installing the application, it still not prompt the user "Use Current Location Prompt" when they select the "Use current Location" .button

Comment: Which exact OS version is installed on your test-device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iPhone caches the location services authorization status. Even if you reinstall the app, it won't prompt you about this. You can reset this (for all apps!) under Settings.app > General > Reset > Reset Location Warnings